# Obtain right position of element returns undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this fragment of HTML containing a navigation menu:

```
 <div class="inner-wraper clearfix">
            <ul class="root">
                <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" class="l_one selected">
                    <a href="#" title="{{menu.Title}}">{{menu.Title}}<span class="arr"></span></a>
                    <ul ng-show="getHasSubMenus(menu)" class="level sl">
                        <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.SubMenus" class="l_two">
                            <a ui-sref="site.shopbycategory({ departmentID: subMenu.DepartmentID , categoryID: subMenu.CategoryID, searchTerm: '' })" title="{{subMenu.Title}}">{{subMenu.Title}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to align the submenu to right position of containing 'li' element, I tried:

```
var theright = $(this).position().right;
```

and

```
var theright = $(this).offset().right - $(this).parent().offset().right;
```

and

```
var theright = $(this).css('right');
```

using the following jquery code but I always get Undefined and NAN instead of a numeric value.

```
$('.inner-wraper > ul').on('mouseenter', '> li', function (event) {

        var theright = $(this).position().right;
        //var theright = $(this).offset().right - $(this).parent().offset().right;                       
        //var theright = $(this).css('right');
        alert(theright);
        $(this).children('ul').css('right', theright);
    });
```

How do I get right position of li element?

Comment: Position only returns left and top values.. see here. https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: I used left: var theright = $(this).offset.left + 130; and it works

Comment: glad to hear. assuming you solved your problem